# Form data not saving to GCP BigQuery

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, velo

I have a GCP BigQuery instance set up and I want to set up my web page to write data to a specific data/collection.  I have successfully established the connection between the wix.com hosted website and GCP.  I have proven out manual editing of records in the wix.com GUI.  Now I would like to accomplish this via code.  The below code is intended to do just that.  The code executes w/out error, but data is not actually being written to the GCP BigQuery table.  I'm assuming I am missing some final step to commit the change of the record, but I'm just not sure what that is.  Any help is much appreciated and I realize I am a newb when it comes to JS so a little patience please :-).

itemID is the item ID passed when the function is called.  I am getting the itemID with the code

```
let item = $w('#dataGCPOperational').getCurrentItem();
saveData(item._id);
```

```
export function saveData(itemID){
  let userEmail = currentMember.getMember().then((member) => {
          return member.loginEmail;
          
      })
  let instagramHandle = $w('#inputInstagram').value
  console.log("instagramHandle " + instagramHandle)
  let market = $w('#dropdownMarket').value
  console.log("market " + market)
  //let optIn2023 = $w('#checkbox2023OptIn').value
  let howManyYrs = $w('#inputYearsParticipated').value
  console.log("howManyYrs " + howManyYrs)
  let howManySixteen = $w('#inputYearsCompleted16').value
  console.log("howManySixteen " + howManySixteen)
  let participatedBefore = $w('#checkboxParticipatedBefore').value
  console.log("participatedBefore " + participatedBefore)
  let sixteenBefore = $w('#checkboxCompleted16Before').value
  console.log("sixteenBefore " + sixteenBefore)
  let exclProgressBoard = $w('#checkboxExcludeFromLeaderboard').value
  console.log("exclProgressBoard " + exclProgressBoard)

  wixData.get("gcpOperationalDB/tblSTMParticipantData", itemID)
  .then(item => {
      item.email = userEmail
      item.instagram = instagramHandle;
      item.market = market
      item.numYearsParticipated = howManyYrs
      item.numYearsSixteen = howManySixteen
      item.participatedBefore = participatedBefore
      item.recordedSixteen = sixteenBefore
      item.excludeFromLeaderboard = exclProgressBoard
    })
    return $w('#dataGCPOperational').save()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Item updated successfully");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Failed to update item: " + err);
    });

}
```

I expect the values of these variables to be written to the appropriate fields in my GCP table referenced with `$w('#dataGCPOperational')`.

```
  let instagramHandle = $w('#inputInstagram').value
  let market = $w('#dropdownMarket').value
  let howManyYrs = $w('#inputYearsParticipated').value
  let howManySixteen = $w('#inputYearsCompleted16').value
  let participatedBefore = $w('#checkboxParticipatedBefore').value
  let sixteenBefore = $w('#checkboxCompleted16Before').value
  let exclProgressBoard = $w('#checkboxExcludeFromLeaderboard').value
```

Comment: another way to debug the issue is Look for any errors in bigquery console under project history. find the job id that you program triggers and look if any errors

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I actually figured out what was wrong. Essentially I was running into a record lock issue where the BigQuery streaming buffer was preventing updates. My workaround/solution is to use an APPEND to store the data each time it changes and then surface the data on my site with a view showing the max record.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially I was running into a record lock issue where the BigQuery streaming buffer was preventing updates. My workaround/solution is to use an APPEND to store the data each time it changes and then surface the data on my site with a view showing the max record.